# 'displayDate' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)eslint

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

Basically I am trying to create a button to show the time and date of the world and this message popped up and I can't figure out how to fix it. My code in HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>What's the date?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">What is today's date?</button>
    <h1 id="now"></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my code in javascript is:

```
function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("now").innerHTML = Date();
}
```

I exprected to show the time and date of today when you click the button but it didn't show.

Comment: So where is the reference to the JavaScript file in your HTML code? There should be a `<script src="......"></script>` in your html

Comment: That lint error/warning is because it has no clue you are calling the function from an inline event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Include your Javascript code within the `<body>` as a `<script> </script>` tag (or include a external .js file), because otherwise how should the browser know what you are trying to run?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=q, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>What's the date?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">What is today's date?</button>
    <h1 id="now"></h1>
    <script>
      function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("now").innerHTML = Date();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```